Did Prahlada Maharaja say that Sanda Amarka were not his Gurus in Bhagavatam?
Did Prahlad ji anywhere say that Sanda Amarka were not his Gurus?
Is it mentioned in Bhagavatam?

Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam [Seventh Canto, Chapter-5] says that Prahlāda expressed his displeasure about learning political philosophy which involved to treat somebody enemy and somebody else friend [sloka: 3]:
Prahlāda certainly heard and recited the topics of politics and
economics taught by the teachers, but he understood that political
philosophy involves considering someone a friend and someone else an
enemy, and thus he did not like it. ॥ 7.5.3 ॥

While addressing to his classmates (sons of Demons), he said that his Guru was Devarishi Nārada [sloka-28].
Prahlāda Mahārāja continued: I received this knowledge from the great
saint Nārada Muni, who is always engaged in devotional service. This
knowledge, which is called bhāgavata-dharma, is fully scientific. It
is based on logic and philosophy and is free from all material
contamination. ॥ 7.6.28 ॥

In Conto seventh, from chapter-5 to chapter-8, no where Prahlāda disrespected his Gurus Sanda and Amarka (sons of Sukrāchārya) and never said that they were not his gurus. He was always obedient and honest to his gurus!
